# After updates pushed on 23 Aug 2016, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS freezes while running videos on Chrome

Tags: 14.04, graphics, google-chrome, intel-graphics, freeze

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a laptop  with following COnfiguration:

RAM: 4GB

Proccessor: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3540 @ 2.16GHz × 4

Graphics: Intel Bay Trail

OS: 64 Bit

There were few packages pushed on 23 August 2016 from Ubuntu update center. The packages are mostly related to  XServer.

After this, my laptop freezes completely while running Google  Chrome. It freezes with Mozilla also, but that happens after a very long run time. But with Chrome, it freezes in 20-30 minutes or so. More faster when I am running Videos on chrome.

Can any one help me on this? It's really irritating to restart my computer using Power button every now and then.

Chrome Version: 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)

Comment: Does clearing the cache help?

Comment: Nope. It keeps happening.  I am still  not able  to  find the root cause  of  the  issue.  The issue  comes when I am running Chrome, Firefox with VIdeos playing in it. It comes faster in Chrome than Firefox. And it comes a lot faster when I open Terminal and do some system work while Chrome is running.

Comment: If anyone can help me which log files to check, that will be great. System log files don't have any log for the time the freeze happens.

Comment: Its freezing while playing Videos also. Anything related to graphics.